# How can I access/install a Powershell prompt or equivalent command prompt within Miniforge (not Miniconda)?

Tags: python, powershell, prompt

I am trying to switch from Miniconda to Miniforge, and would like to access a Powershell prompt or equivalent within Miniforge that would let me install packages and edit my conda settings.

However,  I'm not seeing a Powershell prompt within my miniforge3 folder on my computer. I believe Conda-Forge has one . . . but I'm not sure how to install it without a prompt!

I am trying to avoid using either Miniconda or Anaconda to install/access a Powershell prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post helped me find the answer: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/issues/62

To open up an equivalent to an Anaconda Powershell prompt, I had to first open my Windows command prompt (by typing cmd in the search box), enter the following line, and press enter:
`C:\Users\kburc\miniforge3\Scripts\activate`

This then allowed me to run code like conda config --show channels, just as I would have done within an Miniconda or Anaconda Powershell prompt.

Example of this method in use:

`C:\Users\kburc>C:\Users\kburc\miniforge3\Scripts\activate (base) C:\Users\kburc>conda install matplotlib matplotlib-base mpl_sample_data`

In the first line, I enable conda commands to be used; in the second line, I install matplotlib and a couple other packages.